# Can anyone explain why the x is displaying value 1 instead 2

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I'm trying to brush-up my programming skills. Below program's output is 
'**I'm in else if 1**'. 
I would like to know the reason behind, why the x value is not initialized to 2 instead it is showing 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   if (false)
   {
      cout << "I'm in if " << endl;
   }
   else if (int x=2 && true)
   {
      cout << "I'm in else if " << x << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      int y = x;
      cout << y << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: precedence of operator...

Comment: @iharob: [Yes it does](http://ideone.com/6obqrJ). Variables declared in an `if` header are scoped within both the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: @iharob in fact it *does* compile

Comment: @iharob: `x` is declared if the *if condition* and it compiles [demo](https://ideone.com/l3KjCY)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I didn't know that, and I don't like it...

Comment: Regarding the other answers, if it were a precedence problem, it could be solved with parentheses, but `if((int x = 2) && true)` (or whatever) is a syntax error. And if `=` were an operator here, `if(int x = 2 , 1)` would work (comma has lower precedence than assignment) but that's a syntax error, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to operator precedence,

```
if (int x=2 && true)
```

is parsed as

```
if (int x = (2 && true))
```

so `x = true` so `1`.

Comment: *is seen as*? +1 but I think you can explain better.

Comment: @MukitChowdhury no, it is &&. 2 && true is true, true is 1

Comment: @MukitChowdhury No. `2 & true` is the same as `2 & 1` which is `0`. `2 && true` is the same as `true && true` which is `true` (which is `1` when converted to `int`).

Comment: @MukitChowdhury: no, `2 && true` is `true` whereas `2 & true` is `0`

Comment: then 2 is read here as a boolean 'true', and (true && true) is equal to 'true'. And in x, instead of 'true' a non zero value is assigned. Does this work in this way ?

Answer (score 4):

#### Introduction

This boils down to the grammar involved when writing a *selection statment*, which is what `if` really is.

By reading the relevant section of the standard we find the following:

> `6.4p1` **Selection statements** `[stmt.select]`
>
> > Selection statements choose one of several flows of control
> >
> > ```
> > selection-statement:
> >   if ( condition ) statement
> >   if ( condition ) statement else statement
> >   switch ( condition ) statement
> >
> > condition:
> >   expression
> >   [...] decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
> >   [...] decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list
> > ```

---

#### What does this mean?

When the compiler sees `if (int x=2 && true)` it will parse `2 && true` as the *initializer* for the name introduced by the declaration (`int x =`).

<sup>**Theoretical snippet**</sup>

Your snippet is, semantically, equivalent to the below - which undoubtedly explains why `x` is equal to `1`.

```cpp
 if (false) {
    cout << "I'm in if " << endl;
 } else {
   int x = 2 && true;
   if (x) {
    cout << "I'm in else if " << x << endl;
   }
 }
```

<sup>**Transforming `2 && true` to an `int`**</sup>

```
int x = (2 && true)    =>
int x = (true && true) =>
int x = true           =>
int x = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition in an `if` statement can be an expression or declare something, they cannot be combined (an expression cannot declare anything). `int x = 2 && true` declares `x` and initializes it to `2 && true` which is `true` (or 1 when converted to `int`).

To do what seems to be intended, `x` needs to be declared outside the `if`:

```
int x;
if((x = 2) && true) { ... }
```

Note the parens, logical AND has higher precedence than assignment.

Comment: +1 for being the closest to the truth. `2 && true` is the expression here, used as *initializer-clause* of x's *brace-or-equal-initializer*

Answer (score 0):

This part of code:

```
int x=2 && true
```

works in the following way:

- && (and) has higher priority than = (assignment)
- because of the &&, 2 is converted to a boolean value
- 2 is truey, so 2 is true when it is converted to a boolean
- true && true is true
- because we assign true to an int variable, it is converted to int
- true as int is 1
- as a result, x is initialized by 1

Note, that & is bitwise and and && is boolean and